# coalesce two columns and one column has space

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, case, coalesce

[image]

[image]

I have a table: customer and has three columns. I want to select the first not null column.

Select ID coalesce( columnA, ColumnB)
from customer.

The Expect result should be : 101 AABB.

The actual result is 101 blank.

The columnA may have space, I trim the column.

Select ID coalesce( trim(columnA), ColumnB) from customer.

I get the same result: 101 blank.

How can I get result: 101 AABB?
The ColumnA may have space, null value, and actual value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONCAT`. `NULL` is not same as space.`COALESCE` will return the first non null value and hence you are getting space.

```
select ID,CONCAT(trim(ColumnA),trim(ColumnB)) from customer
```

**EDIT**

```
select ID, 
CASE WHEN ColumnA is null OR trim(ColumnA)=' ' then ColumnB else ColumnA END 
from customer
```

Comment: Hi VK_217, It works if we only have space in ColumnA. We have Null value, space, and actual value in columnA. If we have null value and space in columnA, we select ColumnB, else we select columnA

Comment: @Anson use case statement to determine the value and then decide to pick either columna or columnb

Comment: Hi VK_217, could you edit your statement to select ID,
       CASE WHEN ColumnA is null OR trim(ColumnA)=' ' then ColumnB else ColumnA END
from customer, and I will accept as answer